# Data manipulation - how can I count the number of observations for multiple variables?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 3 vectors:

```
pizza=c("satisfied","dissatisfied","neutral","dissatisfied","dissatisfied")
burger=c("dissatisfied","satisfied","dissatisfied","satisfied","neutral")   
drinks=c("neutral","dissatisfied","neutral","dissatisfied","satisfied")
```

How do I filter them using the `dplyr` package so that it groups the total number of all reactions according to the items?

Comment: Can you please give an example of the expected output?

Comment: pizza burger drinks
dissatisfied     3      2      2
neutral          1      1      2
satisfied        1      2      1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tibble(pizza,burger,drinks) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "food") %>%
  group_by(food) %>%
  count(value)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   food [3]
  food   value            n
  <chr>  <chr>        <int>
1 burger dissatisfied     2
2 burger neutral          1
3 burger satisfied        2
4 drinks dissatisfied     2
5 drinks neutral          2
6 drinks satisfied        1
7 pizza  dissatisfied     3
8 pizza  neutral          1
9 pizza  satisfied        1
```

Comment: `count()` is a grouping function so you can just do `count(food, value)`.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your suggestion. I left it as is for educational benefit to the OP.

Comment: can the same thing be done by group function instead of pivot ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but a slight variation of hello_friend's answer might help: `t(sapply(data.frame(pizza, burger, drinks), table))`

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for dplyr but here is a Base R one-liner:

```
sapply(data.frame(pizza, burger, drinks), table)
```

Data:

```
pizza=c("satisfied","dissatisfied","neutral","dissatisfied","dissatisfied")
burger=c("dissatisfied","satisfied","dissatisfied","satisfied","neutral")   
drinks=c("neutral","dissatisfied","neutral","dissatisfied","satisfied")
```

Answer (score 0):

An option in `base R`

```
table(stack(list(pizza = pizza, burger = burger, drinks = drinks)))
```

Or if we need the long format

```
as.data.frame(table(stack(list(pizza = pizza, burger = burger, drinks = drinks))))
```